# How to reorder cells based on sort criteria programatically SWIFT 4

Tags: uitableview, sorting, core-data, swift3, swift4

I'm trying to reorder cells based on sorting criteria that will be triggered from a segment control. The problem that i am having when sorting it just sorts the labels in the table but some elements like a button that the text will change based on user interaction stays at the same row which do not make sense it should be more with the cell itself. Please see differences when tapped on the distance segment control it sorts the data correctly the problem is the button START ROUTE was pressed when it was at row 2 and changed into IN TRANZIT and now that is sorted it should be at row 1 but that is not the case here. The data that is populating the table is coming from core data. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

[image]
[image]

```
                func sortData() {
                    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
                        dropOffLocations.sort(by: {$0.dateCreated! < $1.dateCreated! })
                    } else if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
                        dropOffLocations.sort(by: {$0.distance < $1.distance })
                    } else if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {
                        dropOffLocations.sort(by: {$0.postcode! < $1.postcode! })
                    }
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }

                @IBAction func segmentChange(_ sender: Any) {
                    sortData()
                }


  @objc func tappedButton(sender : UIButton) {
        if let cell = sender.superview?.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
                let dropOffLocation = dropOffLocations[indexPath.row]
                sender.setTitle("IN TRANZIT", for: .normal)
                sender.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
                dropOffLocation.btnStatus = sender.titleLabel?.text
                sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05882352963, green: 0.180392161, blue: 0.2470588237, alpha: 0.75)

                save(completion: { (true) in
                    dropOffLocation.setValue("IN TRANZIT", forKey: "btnStatus")
                    print(dropOffLocation)
                })

                print(dropOffLocation)
                let destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: dropOffLocation.latitude, longitude: dropOffLocation.longitude)
                let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoordinate)
                let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)

                destinationMapItem.name = dropOffLocation.street
                destinationMapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])

            }
        }
    }



              func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "deliveryAddressCell", for: indexPath) as? AddressCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

                    let dropOffLocation = dropOffLocations[indexPath.row]

                    cell.startBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tappedButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                    cell.startBtn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
                    cell.startBtn.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
                    cell.startBtn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
                    cell.startBtn.titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2)
                    cell.configureCell(dropOffLocation: dropOffLocation)
                    cell.numberLbl.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)

                    return cell
                }


      func save(completion: (_ finished: Bool) -> ()) {
            guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else  { return }
            let dropOffLocations = DropOffLocation(context: managedContext)

            do {
                try managedContext.save()
                print("Succesfully saved data!")
                completion(true)
            } catch {
                debugPrint("Could not save: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(false)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your tableView `cellForRowAt:` method?  I'm guessing you need to store the state of the buttons ("start route" v. "in transit") in your data model, and to use the model data to set them correctly in cellForRowAt:

Comment: @pbasdf Hi I've added the missing parts of the code.

Comment: Yes - you need to keep track of the button state for each dropOffLocation.  You could do that by adding another attribute to your model (perhaps called `status`?).  Then in `tappedButton` you can change the status of the relevant dropOffLocation (and either modify the button title directly, or reload the corresponding cell).  And in cellForRowAt, be sure to check the status and set the title of the button accordingly.

Comment: @pbasdf Than you for your help so far I made the adjustments as you suggested up till cellForRowAt where I'm a bit confused because the data is coming from core data as START ROUTE why would i need to check and set the title again? Also another question do i need in the model to hold a reference of the colour of the button as it changes to a more darker colour? Thanks

Comment: When you call reloadData, the tableView discards the current cells (puts them back in the queue) and then call its datasource methods (eg. cellForRowAt) to rebuild the cells.  The cellForRowAt code gets a cell off the queue and configures it to reflect the correct data.  You need to set the button title again, otherwise it will be whatever it was before the cell was put back in the queue.  No need to hold the colour details: just update the colour in code according to the button status in CoreData.

Comment: @pbasdf I have a small problem that if I close the app and launch it again the status of the button will go back to start route instead of in transit. It doesn’t save the new status in core data. Do you know how to update the value in core data?

Comment: You should be able to update the relevant attribute, then call `save` on the context to ensure the update is saved.

Comment: @pbasdf yeah tried that but it creates an empty cell in core data and when I start the app again it loads that empty cell.

Comment: Any update?  I can't see any reason why you should be getting empty cells.

Comment: @pbasdf Hi I've updated the code and the way it's now it creates an empty cell and still not saving the new value for the status. Any suggestions?

Comment: In your save method, this line `let dropOffLocations = DropOffLocation(context: managedContext)` creates a new, blank drop off location, which is probably the cause of the blank cell in the TV.

Comment: ... and in `tappedButton` try changing `dropOffLocation.btnStatus = sender.titleLabel?.text` to `dropOffLocation.btnStatus = "IN TRANZIT"` - I think there might be something weird happening with the button titleLabel.

Comment: @pbasdf The way it is now or even with your suggestion it changes the title label. My problem is when I close the app and open again the new value is not saved in core data.

Comment: @pbasdf Thank you for your help i managed to figure it out not to record the button title in core data and insteed I created a isINTranzit of type bool and checked against that in `cellForRowAt` and set the title of button there. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi just figured out how to deal with this. First, I added in core data `isINTransit` of type Bool. In the data model init with a false value and when I press the button I set the value to true. Then in `cellForRowAt` do a conditional check if is true then set the button title to IN TRANZIT if false set it to START ROUTE.